# Angular4 router breaks after using `router.navigate()` in Google Sign In callback

Tags: javascript, angular, google-signin, angular-routing

I need to implement Google Sign In in Angular4 app, but I encountered strange issue with routing after using `router.navigate()` in Google Sign In callback.

I set up an example of issue [here](https://rocky-everglades-54530.herokuapp.com), note with steps to reproduce is on the first page.

I also set up the repo with deployed code [here](https://github.com/b2709f1b/angular-4-router-break-on-google-sign-in), example of broken routing is in `angular-4-google-signin` branch, and example of routing working properly with Angular2 is in `angular-2-google-signin` branch. You can see there that Angular2 version routing works properly after the same sequence of actions.

I need to understand whether it is issue with Angular or with me not using its router properly. If I'm not using router properly, please give me a hint of how I can fix it.

Comment: Are you using the exact same code in both?

Comment: @ronenmiller, yes, all router-related logic is the same, I first implemented Angular4 version and then checked out to Angular2 branch and changed only dependencies

Comment: Try adding a catch after the signin's then block and see if you get an error. If so please paste it here

Comment: @ronenmiller, I've got `this.auth2.signIn(...).then(...).catch is not a function` error after adding it, it looks like promise returned from GoogleAuth.signIn() has no `.catch()` method and error can only be caught in second callback function passed to `.then()`

Comment: @ronenmiller, adding `.catch()` block before `.then()` provides the same result, no `.catch()` method

Comment: @ronenmiller and second callback in `.then()` actually catches all errors from google auth

Comment: You should try the following code: 
`this.auth2.signIn()
      .then(
        (res) => {
          this.router.navigate(['another-page']);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      )
    .catch(e => console.log(e));`

Comment: @ronenmiller, yeah, I did it, I changed method to this: ```public onGoogleLogin() {
    this.auth2.signIn()
      .then(
        (res) => {
          this.router.navigate(['another-page']);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem like yours. It seems that there is a 'change' angular did not find. You could try to run you code in the zone.run callback.

I changed my code like this:

before change:

```
this._router.navigate(['dashboard'])
```

after changed:

```
this._zone.run(
    () => this._router.navigate(['dashboard'])
);
```

and it works now!

Answer (score 2):

I have downloaded your code from GitHub (both branches) [(your code)](https://github.com/b2709f1b/angular-4-router-break-on-google-sign-in).
I ran `npm install`, then `ng serve`, and it worked like a charm.
I have running `npm v5.3.0`, `node v6.10.3` installed. So I guess that either you have uploaded the wrong code, or something in your setup is wrong.

I suggest you download your own code and check this out, after you have updated node and npm to latest versions.

For the v4 version, I ran into an error while running `npm install`. I have removed the following section:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1",
    "npm": "3.10.9"
  },
```

from `package.json` file and then install, serve and functionality worked as expected. So again, I would suspect node/npm issue.

Comment: you uploaded from branch `angular-4-google-signin`, right? I see `angular-2-google-signin` branch selected by default in repo, so just checking

Comment: as I mentioned in question, Angular2 version works ok, but Angular4 breaks after Google Sign In

Comment: Sorry will recheck

Comment: Both worked, edited my answer to show which change I made.